# Swapping the stores

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I was wondering if I could swap the stores somewhere in an initializer.
  The thing is, I want to check the window.navigator object for something, and decide which store ember-simple-auth should use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in an initializer that runs before the `'simple-auth'` initializer and modifies the app's `ENV` (`ENV['simple-auth'].store` is the value you'd want to set).

Comment: Hi, how can I do the same thing with ESA 1.0 ? I cannot find any documentation on the configuration options of the new addon

Comment: Cancel my above comment, I found good information here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/pull/602